# css nth-of-type not working on safari (mac)

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I have a css as shown which is not working on my safari (mac).

```
#shows-list li:nth-of-type(32) {
    margin-top: 120px;
}
```

Here is the version of mac which I am using:

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the CSS codes above so that it works on my safari (mac)

Comment: Did you try it in other browsers? Are there at least 32 `li` elements inside that container? Did you spell your selector correctly?

Comment: http://www.cpac.ca/en/programs/ Open this link in safari. You will see a blank space. Its working fine on other browsers.

Comment: That space above the "P"? That's the 32nd `li`. It's doing exactly what you told it to do and adding 120px of space above it...

Comment: Ok, try opening in other browsers. Why there is no blank space in other browsers? why only in safari ?

Comment: I don't see any blank space coming on my chrome (both in windows and mac)

Comment: It has to do with how Chrome deals with CSS Columns and Margin at the top/bottom of each column. They tried to "fix" an issue where the margin on the last element in the previous column was getting added to the top of the first item in the next column. Now Chrome essentially ignores spacing above the first element in a column :( Safari's doing what you would expect. If you don't want that space simply remove that `nth-of-type` with extra margin.

Comment: margin-top is not pushing the 2nd column items in the 1st column in safari whereas in chrome is doing that. Is there any other solution which you can recommend ?

Comment: Now that you know the problem, I suggest you re-ask your question (include screenshots) so you get the community's wisdom. Comments aren't a great place for this discussion.